# javadoc not found error, I am new to java

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm getting error on `MouseWheelDemo`  in the main method 
package mousewheeldemo;

```
import java.awt.*;

public class MouseWheelDemo  extends Frame
{  

  private TextArea address;
  private Button exit;
  public MouseWheelDemo(String title)
  {

    super(title);
    address = new TextArea("Enter Address,5,40");
    exit = new Button("Exit");
    Panel north = new Panel();
    Panel south = new Panel();
    north.add(address);
    south.add(exit);
    this.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    ColorChanger listener = new ColorChanger(this);
    address.addMouseWheelListener(listener);
    exit.addActionListener(listener);


  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Frame f = MouseWheelDemo("Generate Event from Mouse Wheels"); //here i am getting error[enter image description here][1]
    f.setSize(500,300);
    f.setVisible(true);

  } 
}
```

Comment: *what* exactly is the error?

Comment: List EXACT error you are getting, copy entire string / stack

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: mousewheeldemo.MouseWheelDemo.MouseWheelDemo
 at mousewheeldemo.MouseWheelDemo.main(MouseWheelDemo.java:31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `new` keyword before `MouseWheelDemo` constructor call inside `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f = new MouseWheelDemo("Generate Event from Mouse Wheels"); 
    f.setSize(500,300);
    f.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Tank you so much Abishek sir.